# How to create a PHP web page which smart phone users can upload files

Tags: php, android, file-upload, upload

input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile"

This works fine in desktop Browser , but cant upload files from some smart phone Browsers.
How do i resolve this issue? 
How do i create a web page which smart phone users can upload files?

Comment: If that does not work you could at least tell what's happening instead. Explain the situation please.

Comment: File upload not working in android browsers..error is "can`t open this file"

Comment: That is less than i asked for. Please tell the complete flow of the actions.

Comment: I have created a web page which have some text boxes and input type="file" field  in php. Using form submit I am uploading a word document to the server. it works fine in desktop browsers etc crome firefox but it is not working in smart phone browsers, when i click upload button it opens the file manager in phone but after i select a file from sd card   it  saying "can`t open this file" .